# Getting error in Response header Location field

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

We are doing web application scripting using JMeter. In the flow after submitting the application URL is redirecting and we are getting one auth token in the location field of response header which needs to be captured. But, in my script I am getting anerror message in the response header. Could you please help me to fix the error.

**Issue facing**

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 07:42:23 GMT Content-Type:
>   text/html;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
>   includeSubDomains Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Pragma: no-cache X-XSS-Protection: 1;
>   mode=block Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT  Location:
>   https://google.com#error_description=Unexpected+Runtime+Authn+Adapter+Integration+Problem.&state=af0ifjsldkj&error=server_error

**Expected Response Header:**

> HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 13:16:52 GMT Content-Type:
>   text/html;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
>   includeSubDomains Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Pragma: no-cache X-XSS-Protection: 1;
>   mode=block Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT  Location:
>   https://google.com#**code=XisAQ92nQU75ypPxcDt5mMYkzTVwN9SYZcZFRF18**&id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InhsMTZCRHh3NTdKTi0zUHR2cm15QS16V1RnTSJ9.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.s2WVaMvMlKkr7M_o46Sk7dt6YaUKdUNyNl8XEKBYCsnA4OWMK6TS5HCH5Z31zN-_9QaLpDXp68dsvqfv-OH4Zj0r9sqfNwFGQ8ksKhoPxUQw_runiQlbidS9n9EZa7nPexJLAwxfthQR9E7GZQU4E3vG8eStOot8yQP8-YIN-BLsIQFCw5XrPFQRojEW9r6JpLYaVy2IaAUWlXk6wrydS6yo3rQsOBDa0NVQ07xemyk1SmQ4ee3SVbsRpGTbZlQSKNzpa3gJsJDPpF7MQVPedzdrAzsHjOERk9sEDOYeHskhLr5xrZ_glp_mf84OBlvxd21b7G0kLU1BXN9Uz9XCFA&state=af0ifjsldkj

Comment: Can u pls let me know how u resolved this issue